# Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver'

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I´m running an integration test with Maven where my pom file looks like

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${basedir}/target/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <!--<useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

And I have this Spring.context conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">


    <context:load-time-weaver />

    <import resource="classpath*:coreAkkaContext.xml" />


</beans>
```

When I try to initialize all my beans using

```
final GenericXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(resourceLocations );
```

I receive the exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
```

So somehow the test it´s not passing the config of surefire that I passed about the agent

The maven commands is

```
mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test -DforkMode=never
```

Any idea what´s wrong?

Regards.

Comment: I would not expect your Java agent in the target directory. It should reside somewhere in your local Maven repo, I guess - unless you configured another plugin to copy it to target. Have you run the build in debug mode so as to check what really is on the JVM command line?

Comment: That´s what I was expecting looking in the target/class folder there was nothing. Any idea where exactly has to be? Regards

Comment: By the way in the target folder I have spring-instrument-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar I guess that´s fine

Comment: Why do you use `-DforkMode=never`? Is it actually forking a new JVM for the agent to run in with this?

Comment: @NándorElődFekete  it's just to allow debug the mvn when I run with my IDE

Comment: That's fine, but is it __actually__ forking a new JVM with the agent or not? If not, there lies your problem.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete I don't get it but I'll try to remove the argument and see what happens